# update table information based on columns of another table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datatable

I am new in python have two dataframes, df1 contains information about all students with their group and score, and df2 contains updated information about few students when they change their group and score. How could I update the information in df1 based on the values of df2 (group and score)?

df1

```
   +----+----------+-----------+----------------+
    |    |student No|   group   |       score    |
    |----+----------+-----------+----------------|
    |  0 |        0 |         0 |       0.839626 |
    |  1 |        1 |         0 |       0.845435 |
    |  2 |        2 |         3 |       0.830778 |
    |  3 |        3 |         2 |       0.831565 |
    |  4 |        4 |         3 |       0.823569 |
    |  5 |        5 |         0 |       0.808109 |
    |  6 |        6 |         4 |       0.831645 |
    |  7 |        7 |         1 |       0.851048 |
    |  8 |        8 |         3 |       0.843209 |
    |  9 |        9 |         4 |       0.84902  |
    | 10 |       10 |         0 |       0.835143 |
    | 11 |       11 |         4 |       0.843228 |
    | 12 |       12 |         2 |       0.826949 |
    | 13 |       13 |         0 |       0.84196  |
    | 14 |       14 |         1 |       0.821634 |
    | 15 |       15 |         3 |       0.840702 |
    | 16 |       16 |         0 |       0.828994 |
    | 17 |       17 |         2 |       0.843043 |
    | 18 |       18 |         4 |       0.809093 |
    | 19 |       19 |         1 |       0.85426  |
    +----+----------+-----------+----------------+

df2
+----+-----------+----------+----------------+
|    |   group   |student No|       score    |
|----+-----------+----------+----------------|
|  0 |         2 |        1 |       0.887435 |
|  1 |         0 |       19 |       0.81214  |
|  2 |         3 |       17 |       0.899041 |
|  3 |         0 |        8 |       0.853333 |
|  4 |         4 |        9 |       0.88512  |
+----+-----------+----------+----------------+
```

The result

df: 3

```
   +----+----------+-----------+----------------+
    |    |student No|   group   |       score    |
    |----+----------+-----------+----------------|
    |  0 |        0 |         0 |       0.839626 |
    |  1 |        1 |         2 |       0.887435 |
    |  2 |        2 |         3 |       0.830778 |
    |  3 |        3 |         2 |       0.831565 |
    |  4 |        4 |         3 |       0.823569 |
    |  5 |        5 |         0 |       0.808109 |
    |  6 |        6 |         4 |       0.831645 |
    |  7 |        7 |         1 |       0.851048 |
    |  8 |        8 |         0 |       0.853333 |
    |  9 |        9 |         4 |       0.88512  |
    | 10 |       10 |         0 |       0.835143 |
    | 11 |       11 |         4 |       0.843228 |
    | 12 |       12 |         2 |       0.826949 |
    | 13 |       13 |         0 |       0.84196  |
    | 14 |       14 |         1 |       0.821634 |
    | 15 |       15 |         3 |       0.840702 |
    | 16 |       16 |         0 |       0.828994 |
    | 17 |       17 |         3 |       0.899041 |
    | 18 |       18 |         4 |       0.809093 |
    | 19 |       19 |         0 |       0.81214  |
    +----+----------+-----------+----------------+
```

my code to update df1 from df2

```
dfupdated = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=['student No'], suffixes=('', '_new'))
dfupdated['group'] = np.where(pd.notnull(dfupdated['group_new']), dfupdated['group_new'],
                                         dfupdated['group'])
dfupdated['score'] = np.where(pd.notnull(dfupdated['score_new']), dfupdated['score_new'],
                                         dfupdated['score'])
dfupdated.drop(['group_new', 'score_new'],axis=1, inplace=True)
dfupdated.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

but I face the following error

```
KeyError: "['group'] not in index"
```

Comment: Python had no native "datatables", and you haven't shown your own attempt to do anything — making your question impossible to answer.

Comment: what database you are using ? Have you even tried it ?

Comment: @ martineau,I updated my question

Comment: @Utpal Dutt, python with data frames

Comment: so if you print your dfupdated  do you se group column there ? or does it have a suffix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's wrong I ran same and got the answer
giving a different way to solve it

try :

```
dfupdated = df1.merge(df2, on='student No', how='left')
dfupdated['group'] = dfupdated['group_y'].fillna(dfupdated['group_x'])
dfupdated['score'] = dfupdated['score_y'].fillna(dfupdated['score_x'])
dfupdated.drop(['group_x', 'group_y','score_x', 'score_y'], axis=1,inplace=True)
```

will give you the solution you want.

to get the max from each group

`dfupdated.groupby(['group'], sort=False)['score'].max()`

Comment: thanks its work, How could I return the max value of score in each group ?? for dfupdated